# Hello world app with libgdx & RoboVM not running on iOS - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: ios, eclipse, libgdx, robovm

I'm trying to run a libgdx app for iOS for the first time. I'm using the hello world app generated by the setup-ui and trying to run it on the iPhone simulator using robo-vm. When I try to run the app I'm getting this message:

An internal error occurred during: "Launching my-gdx-game-robovm"

Here's the error log:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2013-10-23 11:12:02.701 !MESSAGE An
>   internal error occurred during: "Launching my-gdx-game-robovm". !STACK
>   0 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1    at
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:324)   at
>   org.robovm.compiler.target.ios.IOSTarget.init(IOSTarget.java:497)     at
>   org.robovm.compiler.config.Config.build(Config.java:463)  at
>   org.robovm.compiler.config.Config.access$3700(Config.java:67)     at
>   org.robovm.compiler.config.Config$Builder.build(Config.java:909)  at
>   org.robovm.eclipse.internal.IOSSimulatorLaunchConfigurationDelegate.configure(IOSSimulatorLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:59)
>     at
>   org.robovm.eclipse.internal.AbstractLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(AbstractLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

Running the desktop app works fine.

Please note that although I read that I need a developer account to use libgdx with iOS (I'm new to iOS development), I do not have one, but I don't think the error above reflects that.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is most likely that you haven't agreed to the Xcode terms. Please open Xcode once or run `sudo xcrun clang` from a Terminal.

If you have already agreed to the terms another reason could be that `xcode-select` isn't pointing to the correct path. Run `xcode-select -print-path` in a Terminal to view the current path. Use `sudo xcode-select -switch <path>` to change the path pointed to.

The next version of RoboVM (0.0.6) will show more helpful error messages when these problems occur.

Comment: The reason was the xcode location, that was correct. For some reason, just changing the path did not cut it, I actually had to re-install XCode from the market (I had it as a dmg) for this to work. Big thanks for your work by the way!